# Access Violation exception in c++ while multithreading

Tags: c++, multithreading, sdl-2

```
#include <complex>
#include <thread>
#include "SDL.h"

#define maxt 30

long double map(long double x, long double in, long double im, long double on, long double om) { return (x - in) * (om - on) / (im - in) + on; }

void f(SDL_Window *wn, SDL_Renderer *rn, int x, int y, int maxi, long double minx, long double maxx) {
    int i = 0;
    std::complex<long double> z(0, 0);
    std::complex<long double> c(map(x, 0, SDL_GetWindowSurface(wn)->w, minx, maxx), map(y, 0, SDL_GetWindowSurface(wn)->h, minx, maxx));
    for (i; i < maxi; i++) {
        z = z*z + c;
        if (abs(z) > 2) { break; }
    }
    int col = i == maxi ? 0 : (int)map(i, 0, maxi, 0, 255);
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(rn, col, col, col, 255);
    SDL_RenderDrawPoint(rn, x, y);
}

void fmand(SDL_Window *wn, SDL_Renderer *rn, int maxi, int xn, int xm, long double minx, long double maxx) {
    for (int x = xn; x < xm; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < SDL_GetWindowSurface(wn)->h; y++) {
            f(wn, rn, x, y, maxi, minx, maxx);
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    long double minx = -2, maxx = 2, zf = 0.1;
    int maxi = 256;
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
    SDL_Window *wn = SDL_CreateWindow("Mandelbrot", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 800, 800, 0);
    SDL_Renderer *rn = SDL_CreateRenderer(wn, -1, 0);
    SDL_RenderSetLogicalSize(rn, 800, 800);
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(rn, 0, 0, 0, 255);
    SDL_RenderClear(rn);
    while (1) {
        SDL_RenderPresent(rn);
        //fmand(wn, rn, maxi, 0, SDL_GetWindowSurface(wn)->w, minx, maxx); this line draws the whole mandelbrot set
        std::thread t[maxt];
        for (int i = 0; i < maxt - 1; i++)
            t[i] = std::thread(fmand, wn, rn, maxi, (int)(SDL_GetWindowSurface(wn)->w / maxt * i), (int)(SDL_GetWindowSurface(wn)->w / maxt * (i+1)), minx, maxx);
        for (int i = 0; i < maxt - 1; i++)
            t[i].join();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The code above uses SDL2 to draw a mandelbrot set. The problem occurs when I apply multithreading to it.
I noticed that it works when I do only one thread at a time, but not when they are working simultaneously.

I know my code doesn't look very organized, so I'll answer every question you might want to ask.
Finally, here's the error Visual Studio throws at me:
"Exception thrown at 0x00007FFC48324589 (msvcrt.dll) in SDLTest.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00007FF4AAFA7000."

Comment: Are `SDL_RenderDrawPoint` and `SDL_SetRenderDrawColor` thread safe?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Woops my bad :(

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I might try putting all the values in an array and then drawing them in a for loop, I'll let you know if this solves it.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux well, that made it even worse because all the values where assigned in basically random places, so I just blocked the threads while changing the color and drawing the pixel and it worked. But I still have a question: why is it so slow, even if I use only  8 threads (I have a 12 core 24 threads cpu), and it becomes worse the more I add.

Comment: @LeSgHsW It depends on how much of the work in done in synchronized sections relative to unsynchronized sections. In the worst case, the threads can only run one at a time so adding thread just introduces the overhead of managing those threads without any benefit.

Comment: point by point rendering is going to be slow. You can create streaming texture, lock it, update its pixels (could split that to multiple threads based on lines or rectangles), then unlock and render single rectangle. You can keep threads spawned and waiting if thread creation is noticeable.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux i locked only

`SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(rn, col, col, col, 255);`
`SDL_RenderDrawPoint(rn, x, y);`
@keltar Could You please explain how I can do that? or at least direct me to somewhere i can learn about it?